# Failing to build Haskell project with `persistent-postgresql` on Mac with M1 chip

Tags: postgresql, macos, haskell

I'm trying to build my Yesod web app with GHC 9.0.1 via `stack`

```yaml
resolver: nightly-2021-09-02
```

My application uses PostgreSQL database.  There are custom persist fields in my code derived via `derivePersistField`.  Build failing with following error message:

```sh
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/b9ed0f8360016ada5efeb53015219761394cfd2d563da5d48a402d192c951f0a/9.0.1/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-9.0.1/libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-4UpE2VczKgl8p7NC0fd3Q8-ghc9.0.1.dylib, 5): Symbol not found: _PQclear
  Referenced from: /Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/b9ed0f8360016ada5efeb53015219761394cfd2d563da5d48a402d192c951f0a/9.0.1/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-9.0.1/libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-4UpE2VczKgl8p7NC0fd3Q8-ghc9.0.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace       
 in /Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/b9ed0f8360016ada5efeb53015219761394cfd2d563da5d48a402d192c951f0a/9.0.1/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-9.0.1/libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-4UpE2VczKgl8p7NC0fd3Q8-ghc9.0.1.dylib
```

I have PostgreSQL 13 installed via `brew`.

What is proper setup for PostgreSQL use with `persistent` on Macs with M1 chip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've noticed so many installation issues disappear when we install psql/mysql etc using docker instead of homebrew. Could you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build `persistent-postgresql` having:

- **PostgreSQL** installed via `brew install postgresql`
- **GHC v8.10.7** and **cabal-install** installed via `brew install ghc cabal-install`
- **stack** installed via `brew install haskell-stack`
  *(previously I had  manually installed **stack** and upgraded it to latest git version)*
- Switched my project resolver to **LTS-18.10** to match compiler version to system one (8.10.7)
- Using `stack build --system-ghc` to build my project with **stack**.
- or `cabal build`.

There some drawbacks with this approach:

- brewed **stack** unable to install any GHC and stuck to use system compiler

  > > stack setup
  > I don't know how to install GHC for (OSX,AArch64), please install manually
- `brew install ghc@9` fails with recommendation to build it from source, which is unsupported and it fails indeed:

  > ==> make
  > Last 15 lines from /Users/arthurfayzrakhmanov/Library/Logs/Homebrew/ghc@9/04.make:
  > adc %eax, %eax
  > ^
  > tmp-add_n.s:179:6: error: invalid operand
  > adc %eax, %eax
  > ^
  > make[4]: *** [add_n.lo] Error 1
  > make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  > make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
  > make[1]: *** [libraries/ghc-bignum/gmp/gmp.h] Error 2
  >
  > <... CUT ....>
  >
  > make: *** [all] Error 2
  >
  > Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Generally speaking, **stack** build tool is not needed thanks to **cabal-install 3+** and nix-style store.  However, in my real use case **stack** is required for Yesod development (`yesod devel` relies on **stack**).

---

Some credits

Originally, **Branimir Maksimovic** answered me in Haskell Cafe and suggested to use **cabal** instead of **stack**, and install GHC and cabal via homebrew.

This indeed worked, however my real use case required `stack`.  I supposed that brewed stack could also work.  In fact, this is no quite right, because stack uses system GHC to work.